# fullcalendar edit headerToolbar title

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a simple fullcalendar, it has buttons in the headerToolbar

The question is, how can I change the titles in these buttons?

[image] [image]

Let's say that instead of `month view` it was just `month`, and instead of `Next day`, just `Next`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear'
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    scrollTime: '08:00',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.0/main.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aria-labelled or title values in full calendar are described as hints, in this example to add hints to prev , next button with the help of a option `buttonHints`. so just have to add it as a calendarOption to your code.

in your example add change code as following

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear'
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    scrollTime: '08:00',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline',
    buttonHints: {
       next: 'next label',
       prev: 'prev label',
       month: 'month',
       day: 'day',
       week: 'week'
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

and change the values next label and prev label as you like ..

also adding a codepen working link [here](https://codepen.io/Midhun-pr96/pen/eYbyVYq).

**PS: Also updated with day, week, month navigation's labels.**

Hope it works :)